# biber: undefined subroutine &encode::define_alias

Tags: biblatex, biber, perl

After an update of the OS, I am getting this error:

```
$ biber -v
Undefined subroutine &Encode::define_alias called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Encode.pm line 102.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Encode/Alias.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Encode/Alias.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/Constants.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/Constants.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/Internals.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/Internals.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/parent.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber.pm line 5.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber line 17.
```

I think some perl module is missing, but I dont know which one.

I have been installing modules and there are only two that I couldn't install:

### `Alias.pm`:

```
$ cpan Biber.pm
Reading '/home/nika-zhenya/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 27 Jun 2017 21:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Alias'
Checksum for /home/nika-zhenya/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GS/GSAR/Alias-2.32.tar.gz ok
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring G/GS/GSAR/Alias-2.32.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Alias
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  GSAR/Alias-2.32.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for G/GS/GSAR/Alias-2.32.tar.gz
cp Alias.pm blib/lib/Alias.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Alias ()
chmod 644 "Alias.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Alias.bs blib/arch/auto/Alias/Alias.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap'  Alias.xs > Alias.xsc
mv Alias.xsc Alias.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong   -DVERSION=\"2.32\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.32\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"   Alias.c
In file included from /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE/perl.h:5644:0,
                 from Alias.xs:5:
Alias.xs: En la función ‘XS_Alias_attr’:
/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE/scope.h:232:37: error: se requiere un l-valor como un operador unario ‘&’
 #define SAVESPTR(s) save_sptr((SV**)&(s))
                                     ^
/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE/embed.h:563:44: nota: en definición de macro ‘save_sptr’
 #define save_sptr(a)  Perl_save_sptr(aTHX_ a)
                                            ^
Alias.xs:208:4: nota: en expansión de macro ‘SAVESPTR’
    SAVESPTR(GvCV(gv));
    ^~~~~~~~
Alias.xs:209:13: error: se requiere un l-valor como operando izquierdo de la asignación
    GvCV(gv) = Null(CV*);
             ^
make: *** [Makefile:328: Alias.o] Error 1
  GSAR/Alias-2.32.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

### `Biber.pm`:

```
cpan Biber.pm
Reading '/home/nika-zhenya/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 27 Jun 2017 21:17:02 GMT
Could not expand [Biber.pm]. Check the module name.
Checking 198036 namespaces for close match suggestions
Skipping Biber.pm because I couldn't find a matching namespace.
```

Thanks!

---

Using: 4.11.6-3-ARCH with Cinnamon 3.4.3, x86_64.

Comment: See also https://trac.macports.org/ticket/54351 This seems to be a known bug that appears in MacTeX. As far as I can see the developers of MacTeX have fixed things at their side and submitted a fix to Biber upstream.

Comment: Mmm, the problem is that I am with Linux, I will update the post with that data.

Comment: OK, it could still be the same problem though, if you are not using the pre-compiled binaries (I assume). You probably have to wait for the fix to be released - or edit it in yourself: https://github.com/plk/biber/pull/173/files

Comment: I remove biber and all it dependencies. I reinstalled it with other LaTeX perl module, I fix some bad regex in /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 316 and now biber is not giving any issue but is crashing with `FATAL - Caught signal: SEGV`

Comment: After all of this, I just went back to biber 2.6 and everything is working as expected.

Summary: broken dependencies after system update, unistall everything relates to biber, reinstall again (biber 2.7 and missing perl modules), having regex and FATAL erros and downgrade to 2.6.

Comment: If it is some problem with biblatex, is better to download biber directly from source.

Comment: Mhhh, I would not say that it is necessarily better to get Biber directly from the source. If you get it from your TeX distributuon (which normally ships pre-copiled binaries for all platforms it supports) you can be sure that your `biblatex` and Biber versions are always in sync. If you install one of the two manually, you might get in trouble if one gets updated.

Comment: That is right, the problem here is that biblatex was asking for biber 2.7 and not 2.6, let see if the direct download of biber 2.7 doesn't generate problems...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report for either the Biber developer or distributor/packer. In any case the problem seems to have been solved by switching versions.